# добавить listview в fragment программно

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment

может вопрос окажется глупым но не могу разобраться. гуглил и нигде не сказано как добавить элементы именно в listview с fragment
(я новичок в java)

```
public class order extends Fragment {


    public order() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false);
    }

}
```

в фрагмент перехожу так с MainActivity.java:

```
if (id == R.id.box) {
        setTitle("Грузы");
        order Order = new order();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Fragment, Order).commit();
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_order);
}
```

fragment_order.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".order">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: нашел ответ по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475996/custom-adapter-for-listview-in-fragment-android (странно. вчера весь день не мог найти. а после того как задал вопрос, нашел)

Comment: Задавайте имена классов начиная с прописной буквы. а имена переменных со строчной. а не наоборот. `class Order` и `Order prder = new Order()`

Comment: меня тоже это смутило. но потом лень было править)